# RMarkdown - Knit to Word

Tags: r, datatable, r-markdown, knitr

I am running some reports knitting to HTML and all the formatting is great.
However, I was requested to save the same reports in MS Word. When I knit to Word, all the tables disappear.

I am using basically datatables like this one:

```
datatable(q1_ass,
              rownames = FALSE,
              extensions = "Scroller",
              options = list(pageLength=200, 
                             lengthChange = FALSE,
                             paging = FALSE,
                             columnDefs=list(list(targets=(0), width="20%"),
                                             list(targets="_all", className='dt-head-left')),
                            scrollX = TRUE, deferRender = TRUE,
                            scroller = FALSE))
```

And that is the beginning of my code:

```
---
title: "Survey Results"
author: "XXX Department"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
always_allow_html: true
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: textmate
    includes:
      in_header: logo-2.html
    theme: flatly
    number_sections: no
    toc: yes
    toc_float:
      collapsed: no
      smooth_scroll: yes
  word_document: 
    toc: yes
---
```

Any hints for me?
Thank you kindly :)

My best shot so far was knitting to PDF then opening the file using MS Word. But the formatting is completely off.

Comment: Writing tables to word is a pain.  My best advice is to vary how your tables are processed depending on whether they are feeding into word or html, and use `flextable` to produce the word tables.  I know I've done this before, but I forget how I've checked the output type (word, latex, or html).

Comment: The issue is that you are using `DT::datetable` which is meant to display tables on HTML pages. When you want both HTML and Word Output then I would suggest to use a package which allows for both formats, like e.g. `flextable`.